# Rails 6 how to add an API error with message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to implement error handling for my API client. Everything looks pretty good but except of the error I want to error description from the API either (it's inside `response.body['FirebirdApiError']['ApiStatusDescription']`). Like below:

```
# error handler class
module Errors
  class APIExceptionError < StandardError; end

  BadRequestError = Class.new(APIExceptionError)
  UnauthorizedError = Class.new(APIExceptionError)
  ForbiddenError = Class.new(APIExceptionError)
  ApiRequestsQuotaReachedError = Class.new(APIExceptionError)
  NotFoundError = Class.new(APIExceptionError)
  UnprocessableEntityError = Class.new(APIExceptionError)
  ApiError = Class.new(APIExceptionError)

  def error_class(status)
    case status
    when 400
      BadRequestError
    when 401
      UnauthorizedError
    when 403
      ForbiddenError
    when 404
      NotFoundError
    when 429
      UnprocessableEntityError
    else
      ApiError
    end
  end
end
```

Which is user inside of client class:

```
#client class
class Client
  include ::Errors
  
  def get(path, options = {})
    handle_response(client.public_send(:get, path.to_s, options))
  end
  
  private
  
  (...)
  
  def handle_response(response)
    return response_body(response) if response.success?
    
    raise error_class(response.status)
  end
  
  def response_body(response)
    return if response.body.blank?
    
    response.body
  end
end
```

Which works well but when I'll reach 400 error it will show me `Errors::BadRequestError`. I don't think it's handy in case where the API provides a pretty good description of the cause of the error inside `response.body['FirebirdApiError']['ApiStatusDescription']`. How do I add this message to display with the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add error message when your raise error, right? Maybe you can try

```
raise error_class(response.status).new(response.body['FirebirdApiError']['ApiStatusDescription'])
```

Comment: The syntax could be also `raise error_class(response.status), response.body['FirebirdApiError']['ApiStatusDescription']` but yeah, that's the point!